# Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to install flutter
but when I run cmd flutter doctor an error occurred

Checking Dart SDK version...
'PowerShell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...

Waiting for 1 seconds, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit ...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
Thanks

Comment: have you updated your path for flutter..
Update your path
To run the flutter command in any terminal session, you need to add it to your PATH environment variable:..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this path to path field `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` into your environment variable.

Answer (score 16):

**For windows users only:**

In cases where you are having issues while updating the Dart SDK via the bash shell or the powershell terminal, here is what you do :

**Step 1:** Close all your existing flutter apps and terminals.

**Step 2:** Head over to the `flutter/bin` directory in your flutter installation folder.

**Step 3:** Execute the **flutter.bat** file. (Wait for it to complete)

**Step 4:** Head over to your projects folder > Open a terminal > Run **flutter doctor**.

**Step 5:** Done.

Comment: thank you that works, just needed to close android studio first

Comment: @RidhaRezzag thanks I was wondering why it wasn't starting, closed android studio and it started... like magic :)

Answer (score 2):

Add below path to Environment variable

**User Variables**

C:\flutter\bin; C:\Windows\System32

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

**System Variables**

C:\flutter\bin

C:\Windows\System32\

Answer (score 2):

1.Goto your flutter directory and run

```
git checkout -f [version]
```

for eg:

```
git checkout -f 2.2.2
```

Your issue may be resolved by now try running flutter doctor and after this, you can do

```
flutter channel stable
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue return to git and after executing this line in flutter installed path it's resolved.

```
git reset --merge
```

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem too
but in similiar cases
you can also try deleting lockfile from folder
flutter/bin/cache/lockfile

Answer (score 0):

Try to close all the processes of Dart from task manager and then run flutter doctor command again in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by just simply restarting my device.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, none of the other steps worked for us, but simply installing using the full installation bundle (like `flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable.zip`) worked.

Previously, we were trying to install by pulling the source code from the Flutter repo on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be caused by an antivirus problem (antivirus blocks powershell execution) on the device.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).