# ERROR 80070002. While CHECKING DART SDK VERSION

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run the command "flutter doctor" it shows Checking Dart SDK version...
Then it appears "Internal Windows PowerShell error. Loading managed Windows PowerShell Failed with error 80070002.
Error:Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...

Waiting for 5 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ..
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254803/unable-to-update-dart-sdk-retrying)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running it in cmd with admin privileges.