# flutter Unable to update Dart SDK

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

i can't seem to install flutter.
I downloaded flutter on official page then I followed the installation template as indicated on the site.
then I indicated the bin directory in the environment variables.
then when I execute the command "flutter" or "flutter doctor" the error that appears is "Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying... "

I even uninstall android studio and try again but the same error appears.
please help

Comment: have you looked in to this https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/dart/unable+to+update+dart+sdk.+retrying

Comment: This could be helpful als well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254803/unable-to-update-dart-sdk-retrying